# Creating a dummy index list from a list of repeating inegers

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, count

There's gotta be an easy way to do this, but can't seem to wrap my head around it. I have a list like,

```
l = [3,3,3,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,3]
```

It's a list of integers that repeat a number of times given by the integer, for example if the integer in the list is 5, it repeats 5 times. I would like to preserve the structure of the list and convert it some thing like,

```
l = [3,-1,-1,4,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,2,-1,3,-1,-1,3,-1,-1,3,-1,-1,2,-1,2,-1,5,-1,-1,-1,-1,3,-1,-1,3,-1,-1]
```

Replace the repeated integers with -1. I want to keep the first integer N and replace the repeating integers behind it by N-1 -1's. My problem is the case when the same integer is next to each other. In that case I am getting,

```
l = [3,-1,-1,4,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,-1,3,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,-1,5,-1,-1,-1,-1,3,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]
```

Can any one think of a way to resolve this?

So far I have the code,

```
def idx(List):
    xList = []
    xList.append(List[0])
    for i in range(0, len(List)):
        if (i+1) in range(len(List)):
            if List[i] == List[i+1]:
                xList.append(-1)
            elif tscList[i] != List[i+1]:
                xList.append(List[i+1])
        else:
            break
    return xList
```

It does not take into account repeating integers. I can't really see an easy way to count the position of the integers in a loop without it getting reset or continue to count.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: I did not unaccept it, I just home from work and saw this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier to use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), then use some iteration magic to produce the desired output:

```
from itertools import groupby, cycle

output = [res for k, g in groupby(l) for orig, res in zip(g, cycle([k] + [-1] * (k - 1)))]
```

This produces:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, cycle
>>> l = [3,3,3,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,3] 
>>> [res for k, g in groupby(l) for orig, res in zip(g, cycle([k] + [-1] * (k - 1)))]
[3, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 3, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 2, -1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1]
```

`groupby()` with no key function groups on equality; you get groups of the same repeated number. Thus, you first get the `3`s in a group, then the `4`s, etc. We then zip up each group with a cycling iterable of the group number followed by enough `-1` values to replace the rest of the count. The length of the group determines how often we cycle; `zip()` stops when the shortest iterable (`g`, the group) is done. Thus, `[2, 2, 2, 2]` paired with a cycling `[2, -1]` becomes `[2, -1, 2, -1]`.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I removed the `chain()`; it wasn't really useful here.

Comment: ~~I +1d before I noticed that it's actually not the right output. OP does not want to `cycle` [3, -1, -1] for a long chain of 3s in the input; OP wants a single 3 and everything else replaced by -1.~~ Never mind, I misread the OP! And here I was trying to solve what is actually a much harder problem when you use those kinds of tools ;)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: if the rest of the group needed to be replaced by `-1` regardless of repeats, it is actually just as easy; you can then just cycle over `[-1]` instead.

Comment: ... sort of? You'd need to `chain` a `k` onto the -1 values, yeah?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to use `chain([(k, next(g))], zip(g, cycle([-1])))` and then select only the second element of each tuple.

Comment: Or `zip(g, chain([k], cycle([-1])))`; take your pick.

Comment: Nice, elegant solution thank you. Thanks to everyone else as well!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
def idx(List):
    xList = List
    i=0
    while i < len(List):
        num = xList[i] - 1
        xList[i+1 : i+num+1] = [-1] * num
        i += num + 1

return xList
```

edit: it looks like you'll need to add special cases for anything <= 1, but apart from that, this should work

Comment: bit of a rushed typo, I fixed it

Comment: You're destroying the input. You need to do `xList = List[:]` if you want to avoid doing that

Answer (score 0):

```
In [15]: %paste
def idx(L):
  answer = []
  i = 0
  while i<len(L):
    answer.extend([L[i]]+[-1]*(L[i]-1))
    i += L[i]
  return answer

## -- End pasted text --

In [16]: idx(L)
Out[16]: [3, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 3, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 2, -1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you hit, for example, a `3`, you know that you want the following 2 items to be replaced by `-1` ... so one straightforward solution is simply to go ahead and replace them, by assigning to a slice:

```
>>> my_list = [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2,
...            5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
>>> for i, x in enumerate(my_list):
...     if x != -1:
...         my_list[i+1:i+x] = [-1] * (x - 1)
... 
>>> my_list
[3, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 3, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 2, -1,
 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1]
```